# Internet explorer tries to download index.jsf file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Hey guys I'm trying to get my application to run on Internet Explorer 8.  If I redirect IE8 to my page it just tries to download the JSF file.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Are you sending the correct `Content-Type` in your response? If it's not `text/html` for HTML pages, you'll see similar problems...

Comment: It must be something to do with glassfish security.  I have a filter over /*.  If I change that to something like /admin/* I can display the pages fine.  Hmm.  How do I get around that?  Don't have a problem in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or Safari with the filer like that.

Comment: I changed my login to page to a plain html page instead of a JSF page and it fixed the issue.

Comment: It's hard to tell based on the information given as far. Install Fiddler2 and check what the HTTP response headers contain in cases of failure and success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my login to page to a plain html page instead of a JSF(xhtml) page and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of Internet Explorer don't understand mime type application/xhtml+xml:

http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2004/10/24/application-xhtml+xml/

Change your web.xml configuration file to map the mime type:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xhtml</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```